# Reddit new post trigger a discord.py event

Tags: python, discord.py, bots, reddit

I'm searching to create a bot for discord that send the image and the title of a new post on a subreddit... is it possible to trigger this action when the post is actually posted? If yes, how?

Thanks id advance.

(python)

Comment: you can use selenium or beautiful soup for that

Comment: Do I have to keep my web browser running with selenium?

Comment: Selenium will open a driver browser itself, I think that will have to stay open

Comment: And what about beautifulsoup?

Comment: You can take a look at [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/redditdev/comments/489oyz/notification_for_every_new_post_on_a_subreddit_in/)